# addPreferencesFromResource results in ClassCastException

Tags: android, android-fragments, sharedpreferences, classcastexception

I am populating shared preferences into a `PreferenceFragment`, available as a tab in the `ActionBar`. The preferences are populated in the Fragment's `onCreate` method,

```
public static class WIKPreferenceFragment extends PreferenceFragment
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate ( Bundle bundle )
    {
        super.onCreate( bundle );
        this.addPreferencesFromResource( R.layout.settings_fragment );
    }
}
```

When the tab is selected, the `PreferenceFragment` is added directly,

```
public void onTabSelected ( Tab tab, FragmentTransaction transaction )
{
    transaction.replace( R.id.tab_view_target, new WIKPreferenceFragment() );
    ( (WIKActivity) this.activity ).setTabMemory( tab.getPosition() );
}
```

The content of `R.layout.settings_fragment` is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    <PreferenceCategory android:title="@string/category_proximity_settings" >
        <CheckBoxPreference
            android:key="@+key/USE_PASSIVE_GPS"
            android:summary="@string/summary_use_passive_gps"
            android:title="@string/title_use_passive_gps" />
        <EditTextPreference
            android:inputType="number"
            android:key="@+key/GPS_TIMEOUT"
            android:summary="@string/summary_gps_timeout"
            android:title="@string/title_gps_timeout" />
    </PreferenceCategory>
</PreferenceScreen>
```

With a clean install, the preference fragment appears correctly **when the tab is first selected.** If another tab is selected and this tab is returned to, the following error occurs:

```
05-14 19:23:02.366: E/AndroidRuntime(11744): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-14 19:23:02.366: E/AndroidRuntime(11744): Process: org.eightbeers.android.wik, PID: 11744
05-14 19:23:02.366: E/AndroidRuntime(11744): java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Boolean cannot be cast to java.lang.String
05-14 19:23:02.366: E/AndroidRuntime(11744):    at android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl.getString(SharedPreferencesImpl.java:224)
05-14 19:23:02.366: E/AndroidRuntime(11744):    at android.preference.Preference.getPersistedString(Preference.java:1429)
05-14 19:23:02.366: E/AndroidRuntime(11744):    at android.preference.EditTextPreference.onSetInitialValue(EditTextPreference.java:154)
05-14 19:23:02.366: E/AndroidRuntime(11744):    at android.preference.Preference.dispatchSetInitialValue(Preference.java:1345)
05-14 19:23:02.366: E/AndroidRuntime(11744):    at android.preference.Preference.onAttachedToHierarchy(Preference.java:1140)
05-14 19:23:02.366: E/AndroidRuntime(11744):    at android.preference.PreferenceGroup.addPreference(PreferenceGroup.java:163)
05-14 19:23:02.366: E/AndroidRuntime(11744):    at android.preference.PreferenceGroup.addItemFromInflater(PreferenceGroup.java:104)
05-14 19:23:02.366: E/AndroidRuntime(11744):    at android.preference.PreferenceGroup.addItemFromInflater(PreferenceGroup.java:45)
05-14 19:23:02.366: E/AndroidRuntime(11744):    at android.preference.GenericInflater.rInflate(GenericInflater.java:488)
05-14 19:23:02.366: E/AndroidRuntime(11744):    at android.preference.GenericInflater.rInflate(GenericInflater.java:493)
05-14 19:23:02.366: E/AndroidRuntime(11744):    at android.preference.GenericInflater.inflate(GenericInflater.java:326)
05-14 19:23:02.366: E/AndroidRuntime(11744):    at android.preference.GenericInflater.inflate(GenericInflater.java:263)
05-14 19:23:02.366: E/AndroidRuntime(11744):    at android.preference.PreferenceManager.inflateFromResource(PreferenceManager.java:272)
05-14 19:23:02.366: E/AndroidRuntime(11744):    at android.preference.PreferenceFragment.addPreferencesFromResource(PreferenceFragment.java:285)
05-14 19:23:02.366: E/AndroidRuntime(11744):    at org.eightbeers.android.wik.activity.SettingsTab$WIKPreferenceFragment.onCreate(SettingsTab.java:27)
05-14 19:23:02.366: E/AndroidRuntime(11744):    at android.app.Fragment.performCreate(Fragment.java:1688)
05-14 19:23:02.366: E/AndroidRuntime(11744):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:860)
05-14 19:23:02.366: E/AndroidRuntime(11744):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1063)
05-14 19:23:02.366: E/AndroidRuntime(11744):    at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:684)
05-14 19:23:02.366: E/AndroidRuntime(11744):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1450)
05-14 19:23:02.366: E/AndroidRuntime(11744):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:444)
05-14 19:23:02.366: E/AndroidRuntime(11744):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
05-14 19:23:02.366: E/AndroidRuntime(11744):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
05-14 19:23:02.366: E/AndroidRuntime(11744):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
05-14 19:23:02.366: E/AndroidRuntime(11744):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5105)
05-14 19:23:02.366: E/AndroidRuntime(11744):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-14 19:23:02.366: E/AndroidRuntime(11744):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
05-14 19:23:02.366: E/AndroidRuntime(11744):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:792)
05-14 19:23:02.366: E/AndroidRuntime(11744):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:608)
05-14 19:23:02.366: E/AndroidRuntime(11744):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Some potentially-helpful data points:

- This error does not occur when the `CheckBoxPreference` is commented-out, or if the `EditTextPreference` is commented-out (i.e., everything works if there is only one preference; of course, I'd like to have more than one, more than two, even)
- This error does not occur if preferences are not reloaded in `onCreate` if they've already been loaded; however, when this is changed no preferences appear at all when the tab is reselected
- This error persists through clearing of user data, restarting Eclipse, uninstalling of the app, project cleans, and phone reboots (okay, just one); with exception to the phone reboot (since I only tried it once), it persists through any combination of the previous
- To make uninstalls easier, I renamed the app from  `WIK` to `AAWIK`; however, in the Settings -> Application Manager window the app still appears alphabetized as `WIK`. Everywhere else in the UI --- app drawer, uninstall pane, notifications, etc. --- it is AAWIK; this might just be an extreme caching issue? (**Edit:** this last one was addressed by just letting the phone sit, idle, long enough for me to type this question; no longer a useful data point, all other issues still persist.)

Comment: The problem seems to be that you are storing `Boolean` but while fetching it back, it is assigned to a `String` variable

Comment: Agreed, except I'm not [directly] storing/fetching any variables. I doubt that this would be a bug in `addPreferencesFromResource`, but I've been wrong before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was solved by switching the `android:key="@+key/[keyname]"` in the XML for `android:key="[keyname]"`.

I do not intend to accept my answer immediately since I have no idea of why this worked, and Google has not been forthcoming.

Answer (score 0):

Key should be stored as string in prefs.xml (or another name if you want)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="pref_key_gps" translatable="false">pref_key_gps</string>
</resources>
```

you should replace:

```
android:key="@+key/USE_PASSIVE_GPS"
```

to:

```
android:key="@string/pref_key_gps"
```

Answer (score 0):

### Chinese

现在碰到的问题是，`addPreferencesFromResource ClassCastException Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.String`

我所使用到的控件 `<EditTextPreference .../>`

我的业务场景：

1. 通过 `EditTextPreference` 处理的数据都是数字。
2. 首次将数据写入 xml 文件的工作不是通过 `EditTextPreference` 完成的；我是手动完成的，使用的方法是 `putInt`
3. 在加载包含 `EditTextPreference` 布局的时候报错。

错误原因，在 `EditTextPreference` 类内部所维护的数据是通过 `putString` 和 `getString` 来维护的。
所以我只需要将手动部分设置成 `putString` 即可解决问题。

### English

My problem is : `addPreferencesFromResource ClassCastException Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.String`

The widget I am using is: `<EditTextPreference .../>`

My business scene is:

1. `EditTextPreference` only contrue numbers.
2. I write data to `xml` file by `SharedPerference.Editro.putInt()` ,not done by `EditTextPreference' ,in the first time .
3. **App creash when load `EditTextPreference` layout.**

The cause of the problem is :

- Inside the `EditTextPreference` class , data maintained by `putString` and `getString` .But I used is `putInt`
- **So change `putInt` to `putString` can fix the problem**